# Stack row under row from two different dataframe using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

> `df = pd.DataFrame ([{'col1':1,'col2':2},{'col1':5,'col2':6},{'col1':9,'col2':10}],index = ['A', 'Z', 'B'],columns=['col1','col2']) df1 = pd.DataFrame ([{'col1':3,'col2':4},{'col1':7,'col2':8},{'col1':11,'col2':12}],index = ['A', 'Z', 'B'],columns=['col1','col2'])`

That's a sample cope